# Column space of stochastic matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, probability-distributions, vector-spaces

Consider an arbitrary matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$. Denote the column space of $M$ as $\mathcal{C}(M)$.

Is it always possible to construct a *right stochastic* matrix $S$ such that $\mathcal{C}(M) \subseteq \mathcal{C}(S)$?

Of course the new matrix $S$ can have more columns. Ideally, I would like a procedure for constructing $S$ that uses a reasonably small number of columns (i.e. linear in $m$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If $m > n/2$, then $n$ is $O(m)$, and you can take the matrix $S$ to be the identity.

If $m < n/2$, then you can do the following:

The columns of $M$ form a spanning set for $C(M)$, right? Let's call the $i$th column $c_i$. Split $c_i = p_i + n_i$, where $p_i$ has all the positive-or-zero entries, and $n_i$ has the negative entries. (I.e., $p_i$ is $c_i$ with all negative entries replaced by zeroes). Divide each $p_i$ and $n_i$ by the absolute value of its largest entry, and then divide each by $2m$; negate the $n_i$ vector as well. Call the resulting vectors $p'_i$ and $n'_i$  Now the matrix $H$, whose columns are all the $p'_i$ and $n'_i$ vectors, has the same column space as $M$, and $2n < m$ columns. But it's not right-stochastic: many rows may sum to a number less than one. (Each entry in each column is less than $m/2$). Let $v$ be the sum of the columns, and let $S$ be the matrix $H$ with the column $1 - v$ appended, and then enough zero-columns to make it square. Then $C(S)$ contains $C(M)$, and has $2m+1 = O(m)$ nonzero columns.

Example: 
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
3 & -1 \\
1 & 1  \\
-4 & 0 \\
2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then $m = 2, n = 3$. And initially, 
\begin{align}
p_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
3  \\
1   \\
0 \\
2 \\
0
\end{bmatrix},
n_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
0  \\
0   \\
-4 \\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix},
p_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
0  \\
1   \\
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{bmatrix},
n_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
-1  \\
0   \\
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix},
\end{align}
After division by the largest absolute entry of each vector, and by $2m = 4$, and negation of the $n_i$s, we have
\begin{align}
p'_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
1/4  \\
1/12   \\
0 \\
1/6\\
0
\end{bmatrix},
n'_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
0  \\
0   \\
1/4 \\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix},
p'_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
0  \\
1/4   \\
0\\
0\\
1/4
\end{bmatrix},
n'_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
1/4  \\
0   \\
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix},
\end{align}
The matrix $H$ is then
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1/4 & 0 & 0 & 1/4 \\
1/12 & 0 & 1/4 & 0 \\
0 & 1/4 & 0 & 0 \\
1/6 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1/4 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
The column sum for $H$ is the vector
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1/2 \\
1/3  \\
1/4 \\
1/6 \\
1/4
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
and when we append this to $H$ we get the matrix $S$ (with no zero-columns, because $n = 2m+1$, rather than being larger).

$$
S = \begin{bmatrix}
1/4 & 0 & 0 & 1/4 & 1 - 1/2\\
1/12 & 0 & 1/4 & 0 & 1 - 1/3\\
0 & 1/4 & 0 & 0 & 1 - 1/4\\
1/6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 - 1/6\\
0 & 0 & 1/4 & 0 & 1 - 1/4
\end{bmatrix}
$$

It's true that in this case, $S$ might as well be the identity, but I wanted to show you the process for a real example, and this was the first that came to mind.